# Regular expression to handle two different file extensions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that takes a file of name
"abcd_04-04-2020.txt" or "abcd_04-04-2020.txt.gz"

How can I handle the "OR" condition for the extension. This is what I have so far

```
if(fileName.matches("([\\w._-]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}.[a-zA-Z]{3})")){
    Pattern.compile("[._]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\.");
}
```

This handles only the .txt. How can I handle ".txt.gz"
Thanks

Comment: Also, do you only want to match `.txt` and `.txt.gx` or are you also fine with matching `.tar.gz` and other stuff?

Comment: Just .txt and .txt.gz. I now I have to use a "|" but I am getting lost with this

Comment: So why not use `\.txt(\.gz)?`?

Comment: Why do you need to match `.txt OR .txt.gz` and treat them the same way? I mean, if you already match `.txt` it's pointless to keep searching for `.gz` right after.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with a single regular expression?  What’s wrong with `if (fileName.matches("[\\w._-]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}.[a-zA-Z]{3}") && (fileName.endsWith(".txt") || fileName.endsWith(".txt.gz")))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `.[a-zA-Z]{3}` with `.txt(\.gz)`

```
if(fileName.matches("([\\w._-]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).txt(\.gz)?")){
   Pattern.compile("[._]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `endsWith` instead complex regex

```
if(fileName.endsWith(".txt") || fileName.endsWith(".txt.gz")){
 Pattern.compile("[._]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
^[\w-]+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.txt(?:\.gz)?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**]

> **`^,$`** - Matches start and end of the test string resp.
>
> **`[\w-]+`** - Matches word character along with hyphen one or more times.
>
> **`\d{}`** - Matches digits as many numbers as mentioned in the curly braces.
>
> **`(?:\.gz)?`** - Represents non-capturing group matching `.gz` **zero or one time because of ? quantifier**. You could have used `|` alternation( or as you were expecting **OR**) but this is legible and more efficient too.

You can find the demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/XrIvbt/3)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVA:**

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Main
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w-]+\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\.txt(?:\\.gz)?$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "abcd_04-04-2020.txt\nabcd_04-04-2020.txt.gz\nsomethibsnfkns_05-06-2020.txt\n.txt.gz";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the implementation of the above regex in java in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/S19W8RCo8)

**NOTE:** If you want to match for valid dates also; please visit [**this.**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want (following from the direction you were going) is this:

```
[\\w._-]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\.[a-zA-Z]{3}(?:$|\\.[a-zA-Z]{2}$)
```

At the end, I have a conditional statement.  It has to either match the end of the string (`$`) OR it has to match a literal dot followed by 2 letters (`\\.[a-zA-Z]{2}`).  Remember to escape the `.`, because in regex `.` means "match any character".

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, the `$` is a good catch.  As far as using literals, that's not how the OP had it in their example, and all the other answers seem to be doing that anyway, so I will leave my answer as it is (fixing the `$`) and let the OP decide what they really wanted.

Comment: To date there are 5 other answers, 4 of which treat "txt" and "gz" as literals. To me, matching file names ending with a period followed by exactly two letters makes no sense. The fact that the OP's regex does that is almost irrelevant.

Comment: I can't know what the OP's intentions are, I agree that it makes little sense in the given context, but maybe they want to match the file extension `.rtf.gz` as well.  I have given an alternate solution that is different to the others, and I will let the OP decide which approach is "correct" for their needs.

Answer (score 1):

? will work for your required | . Try adding

```
(.[a-zA-Z]{2})?
```

to your original regex

```
([\w._-]+[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}.[a-zA-Z]{3}(.[a-zA-Z]{2})?)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way of doing it:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w._-]+_\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}(\\.txt(\\.gz)?)$");
```

Then you can run the following test:

```java
String[] fileNames = {
        "abcd_04-04-2020.txt",
        "abcd_04-04-2020.tar",
        "abcd_04-04-2020.txt.gz",
        "abcd_04-04-2020.png",
        ".txt",
        ".txt.gz",
        "04-04-2020.txt"
};

Arrays.stream(fileNames)
        .filter(fileName -> pattern.matcher(fileName).find())
        .forEach(System.out::println);

// output
// abcd_04-04-2020.txt
// abcd_04-04-2020.txt.gz
```